# Incorrect JSON data format

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jsonp, highcharts

I am trying to create some JSON to be used for displaying a chart using Highcharts

http://www.highcharts.com/

I have copied one of their examples:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

Click "View Options" under the graph to see the source. There is also a JSFiddle there to play with

If I copy that locally it all works fine.

The problem is when I try to use my own data source.

I have an ASP.Net MVC controler which is spitting out a list of arrays, just like their data source. However, that doesn't work.

Their datasource looks like this
http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

and they retrieve it like this

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
```

So I thought I'd take a step back and copy thier data exactly and put it in a text file on my server and try that:

So I tried this

```
$.getJSON('/data.txt', function (data) {
```

and this

```
$.get('/data.txt', function (data) {
```

but neither work

I have also tried using both `JSON.parse` and `jQuery.parseJSON` after  retrieving the data, but again - that doesn't seem to work

I am also wondering what the ? is at the start of their data

Their data looks like this

```
?([[<some data>],[some data]]);
```

I don't get any error message, the graph just doesn't display

any ideas?

*SOLVED IT*

Just need to retrive the data and turn it into an array and pass it to the chart.

Needs to be an array, not JSON

Comment: I have the EXACT same problem at the moment... I don't suppose you can give a little more info on how you solved it? Trying to integrate Highcharts in to a project and I can't get why their demo works and using my own doesn't... having problems understanding the other answers... +1'ed you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That datasource is ouputting JSONP, which is for cross-domain AJAX requests.  It's not valid 'raw' JSON because of that extra `callback(...)` wrapper.

Read up about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/   under the 'dataType' section.

Comment: If the url you're requesting is NOT on your own server, it'll almost always be considered a cross-domain request and be ignored/terminated by the JS engine. There's no rule that you CAN'T use jsonp for a 'local' ajax request, it's just not necessary and adds a bit of extra overhead.

Answer (score 2):

As you say in your tags, it's not JSON, it's JSONP. Do not parse it, catch it with a callback. Use `jQuery.getScript` to do it, and define `function callback(data)`. Inside that function, `data` should contain the (parsed) object. Also, replace the `?` in the URL with `callback` (or whatever you named your function) - `?` is not a valid identifier in JavaScript, so `?([....])` is nonsense.